# Calculation of the integral $(2\pi)^{-1/2} \int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^{-ist}}{\sqrt{s}} ds= \frac{1+i}{2}t^{-1/2}$.

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

My task is in the title, how to calculate this integral, I know that the solution should be: $(1+i)/2 t^{-1/2}$, but I don't see how to calculate this integral excplicitly, I tried Mathematica to show me the steps but to aveil.

Perhaps residue theorem in complex analysis?

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{0}^{n}\frac{e^{-ist}}{\sqrt{s}}\space\text{d}s=$$
$$\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\sqrt{it}}\space\space\space\text{for}\space\Im(t)<0$$

Comment: why is that true? BTW the upper limit of the integral is $n$ and not $a$ obviously.

Comment: Evalute the undefinite integral and you'll see!

Comment: @JanEerland why is that true? BTW it should be $n$ instead of $a$.

Comment: Why do ask this twice!

Comment: You are right it's a simple Poission integral. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome!